# It's been asked before about .andriod_secure folder and/or file, but why is this file dated 12/31/69 when the andriod system had not been invented?

Tags: external-sd

.android secure folder or file in my memory card for my LG STYLO AND LG STYLO 3 PHONES date of file 12/31/69

Comment: When this got in my first phone (2015)and sometime in(2017) I found the file and it was fine until 11/14/17. Had to get a new phone 01/03/18 I found the file again after loading my memory card now it's in here. I hope it's not associated with a virus and/or malware. Also I'll be monitoring this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Probably just corrupted time stamp on your file system. So Android rewrote it to default Unix Time. Read about Unix time [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (Unix Epoch is 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC)